# Enviar por POST

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, post, url, http-get

Buenos días, tengo un problema, porque estaba utilizando una web enviando los datos por GET y claro ahora soy consciente de esto y quiero modificarlo a POST para que no se visualicen los datos.
Los datos de GET los enviaba meidante URL de la siguiente manera:

```
 <td>
 <a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo urlencode($r->acronimo); ?>"><img src="icon_editthis.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
 </td>
 <td>
 <a href="?action=eliminar&acronimo=<?php echo urlencode($r->acronimo); ?>"><img src="delete.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
 </td>
```

Ahora la idea es como modificar eso para enviarlo pos POST.

Mi formulario es este el cual debe permitir modificar o ingresar datos, que por ejemplo seleccionaba editar o eliminar registros desde el codigo que ingrese antes.

```
<form action="?action=<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? 'actualizar' : 'registrar'; ?>" method="POST" class="pure-form pure-form-stacked" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__POST('acronimo') : ''; ?>" />

 <table style="width:500px;">
 <tr>
 <th style="text-align:left;">Acronimo</th>
 <td><input type="text" name="acronimo"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__POST('acronimo') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <th style="text-align:left;">Categoria</th>
 <td><input type="text" name="categoria"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__POST('categoria') : ''; ?>" style="width:100%;" required/></td>
 <td colspan="2">
 <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Guardar</button>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>
```

Asi que en resumen es puedo utilizar URL para pasar por POST o como deberia hacerlo?

Si no fuera posible, como podria serlo entonces,gracias de antemano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para enviar la información mediante post debes enviar los datos utilizando un form.

Por ejemplo:

```html
 <td>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editar" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? php echo urlencode($r->acronimo); ?>" />
    <input type="image" src="icon_editthis.png" name="submit" />
  </form>
 </td>
 <td>
  <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="eliminar" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<? php echo urlencode($r->acronimo); ?>" />
    <input type="image" src="delete.png" name="submit" />
  </form>
 </td>
```

Comment: Perfecto Asier, muhcisima sgracias por tu ayuda.